# Combinatorial Proof, Binomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following question:

> Give a combinatorial proof that if $0\le a,k\le n$ are integer than $$\sum_{b=0}^k\binom{a}{b}\binom{n-a}{k-b}=\binom{n}{k}.$$

I'm new to the notion of a **combinatorial proof**, I understand that it's a proof by *counting*, i.e. showing the two expressions are in fact counting the same objects, instead of an **algebraic proof.**

Now, I know $\binom{n}{k}$ represents the ways of choosing *k* objects from *n* objects. I know this may be obvious to some, but can someone lead me to the correct way of thinking for interpreting the left-hand side? 
Am I right in saying it is something like the sum of all the different *(k-b)-subsets* from a collection of *(n-a)* objects, or am I completely wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are on the right track.

Comment: Can you tell me something to keep the ball rolling?

Comment: Every sumand on the left side gives the number of ways to choose $b$ elements out of $a$ objects and $k-b$ elements out of the remaining $n-a$ objects. If this is summed over all the possible $b$, we have the number of ways we can choose $k$ (the total number we choose) out of $n$ (the total number of availabe objects).

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/671585/combinatorial-proof-question

Comment: **Do not delete.** The dupe target is a substitution away from this, which most people searching for this identity will probably not immediately recognize.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $a$ of the objects are red, and $n-a$ of the objects are blue, and try to make sense of how the left-hand side is dividing it up "how many ways are there to pick $k$ of the $n$ objects?" into a sum of smaller `how-many-ways-are-there`'s

Answer (score 1):

The right-hand side is the number of $k$-element subsets of $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. The term $$\binom{a}{b}\binom{n-a}{k-b} $$
is the number of $b$-element subsets of $[a]$ times the number of $(k-b)$-element subsets of $[n]\setminus [a]$, and each $k$-element subset of $[n]$ is the disjoint union of a $b$-element subset of $[a]$ and a $(k-b)$-element subset of $[n]\setminus[a]$. Therefore the sum over $b$ yields the number of $k$-element subsets of $[n]$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint use vandermondes identity $$\sum {m\choose r}{n\choose k-r}={m+n\choose r}$$

Comment: Not sure this would count as a "combinatorial proof"?

Comment: Pardon the pun...